# Could not connect the action cancelAction: to target of class NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I'm new to mac development. I developed an application using the `NSTabView` in which al worked fine for me.

But later I wanted to change the UI so I used `NSSplitView` in this I'm able to display the xib, but the button action are not happening, and I'm getting an error:

> **Could not connect the action cancelAction: to target of class NSViewController**".

```
- (IBAction)cancelAction:(id)sender
{
    [self enableNewProductAction];
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you'll have an object in your XIB file that has its class set to `NSTableView` instead of your custom subclass. Find that and change it, and you'll be set.

Comment: i dint get from where should i change it..can u help.